# Multiple product attribute inventory database design

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a database to build based on inventory for my shop.   This is the current data that I have put into tables. This is the package:

[image: the package]

This is the product attribute:

[image: attributes]

This is the table to produce

[image: inventory list]

The problem is, each product has different packages. The data shown is the product that has 2 packages, "color" and "power".

So the question is:  how to do "color" and "power" as column on the database?
and what will happen if it has more than 2 packages?

I am using MySQL for this.

What I'm going to do is to track the quantity,

```
product-23 : white, 100 = 30qty  
product-23 : white, 50 = 30qty  
product-23 : black, 100 = 30qty
```

What I have is 2 tables "package" and "values", includes already have tables like product that has product id.

So whenever one user is trying to purchase product-23 : white, 100, it will check the quantity on the database.

[Here is the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e4462/4)

Answer (score 1):

You have basically created a basic Key Value Store. See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/607/what-is-a-key-value-store-database) for more details on that. You will need to make use of the `PIVOT` command to get the result you need. Check [here](http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-a-table-in-mysql/) for that.

Comment: does it means that i have to create the "joined tables" first to do the    PIVOT ?, i mean, does the initial data should be the "all combined data" first or it should be like the one "package" and "values" on my question?, sorry I'm quite new in [tag:db-design]

Comment: OK I thought you were describing the tables you had already designed. Database design is very important and difficult to change later on. You want to get this right from the outset. I recommend you start here: http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/Relational_Database_Design.html and then research 3rd normal form. I wouldn't go too in depth because what you're looking to do seems quite simple but the more you know the better it will be.

Comment: i already normalize the raw data into the database. its just that I'm having trouble on how to create/handle the db-table for the "stock"/"qty"